# Why doesn't this function TransformedDistribution work?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

According to the information [in this post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform#Implementation), we know that ${\displaystyle z={\sqrt {-2\ln U_{1}}}\cos(2\pi U_{2})}$ follows a normal distribution, and the datas generated supports this view.

```
data = Table[Sqrt[-2 Log[RandomReal[]]] Cos[2 π RandomReal[]], 
   10000];
ListPlot[data // BinCounts[#, {Min[data], Max[data], 0.05}] &, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

But the following code can't plot the probability density function of ${\displaystyle z={\sqrt {-2\ln U_{1}}}\cos(2\pi U_{2})}$, and I want to know how to solve it, even if the numerical approximation is used.

```
    dist = TransformedDistribution[
  Sqrt[-2 Log[U1]] Cos[2 π U2], {U1 \[Distributed] 
    UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], 
   U2 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]}]
Plot[PDF[dist, z], {z, 0, 1}, Filling -> Axis]
```

Comment: `MomentGeneratingFunction[dist, z]` is identical to `MomentGeneratingFunction[NormalDistribution[0, 1], z]`, and `Mean[dist]` is 0 and `Variance[dist]` is 1. So I don't know why it cannot figure out it's a normal distribution. `Show[
 Histogram[RandomVariate[dist, 100000], 2000, "PDF"],
 Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x], {x, -4, 4}]
 ]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Form the [`TransformedDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedDistribution.html) in steps.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

dist1 = TransformedDistribution[Sqrt[-2 Log[U1]], 
   U1 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[]];

dist2 = TransformedDistribution[Cos[2 π U2], 
   U2 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[]];

dist = TransformedDistribution[x*y,
   {x \[Distributed] dist1, y \[Distributed] dist2}];
```

**EDIT:** Evaluating the `PDF`

```
PDF[dist, x]

(* Piecewise[{{1/(E^(x^2/2)*Sqrt[2*Pi]), x != 0}}, 0] *)
```

Except for a discontinuity at `x == 0` this is the `PDF` for a standard normal distribution

```
PDF[NormalDistribution[], x]

(* E^(-(x^2/2))/Sqrt[2 π] *)
```

For a continuous distribution any specific value has measure zero so the difference makes no difference.

**END EDIT**

```
Show[
 Plot[Evaluate@PDF[dist, z], {z, -4, 4},
  PlotStyle -> Thin,
  Filling -> Axis],
 Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[], z], {z, -4, 4},
  PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

Drawing data from the transformed distribution,

```
data = RandomVariate[dist, 10000];

Show[
 Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF"],
 Plot[Evaluate@PDF[dist, z], {z, -4, 4}]]
```

[image]